# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not visible Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am fairly new to Selenium and C# and need some help. I've been following some online tutorials to create some based selenium tests but now I'm trying to apply them to a different site.

The issue I have is that there is a radio button which I cannot select. I get the

> error: **OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException**

I have looked at many posts and tried several things, but I cannot get it to work. I'm not sure if this is due to my code not working or if I need to try something else.

The website I'm using is:[url](https://quote.flowenergy.uk.com/) 
After entering a postcode, an email address and clicking next you are required to select a fuel type but I cannot find any of the elements to select.

I have tried using `IJavaScriptExecutor`, adding a wait and trying to find by Id and xpath but nothing seems to work. I've also tried maximizing the browser

here is my code:

```
 namespace TestAutomation
 {
   class SelectFuelObject
   {
    public SelectFuelObject()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(PropertiesCollection.driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "dualFuel")]
    public IWebElement btnFuelType { get; set; }

    public void FuelType()
    {
        btnFuelType.ClickOnInvisibleElement();
    }
   }
}
```

Javascript class

```
namespace TestAutomation
{
    public static class HiddenElements
    {
        public static void ClickOnInvisibleElement(this IWebElement element)
        {
           ((IJavaScriptExecutor)PropertiesCollection.driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].hidden = false;", element);
            element.Click();
        }
    }
}
```

PropertiesCollection class

```
    class PropertiesCollection
    {
        //Auto-Implement Property
        public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the wait I tried which just results in a time out after the allotted time

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("DualFuel")));
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: You are probably trying to click the wrong element, something that looks like the radio button, but is hidden. Please post the relevant `html` directly in the question as per the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for the radio button and surrounding `html` you're trying to click.

Comment: With selenium you can use xpath so just go in developer mode with chrome, highlight the radiobutton so it shows you the html that goes with it and right click the html get xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` with `id` "DualFuel" is not a visible input, but it is contained in what I think you're trying to click.

Try this instead:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = ".opt.dual")]
public IWebElement btnFuelType { get; set; }
```

This will get the `div` that contains your input. You could also try clicking the `label` with the `for` attribute "dualFuel"

Then you can just click the element with `btnFuelType.click()`. If you run into an error with it not being clickable or present, let me know in a comment. There shouldn't be any reason to use the `IJavaScriptExecutor` in this, or most cases.

Comment: @RyanHoward glad to hear it :) Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful. Best of luck!